# Hide CMD window after using START to run a network application

Tags: cmd, unc

I have an application that is run over a network.  I need to be able to run this application from a batch file, and had ended up using this:

```
pushd \\server\folder
start /wait program.exe
```

Aside from the message saying...

```
\\server\folder
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. 
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

...it works fine, but the CMD window lingers.  I know that /wait is the cause, but it appears that I can only get the program to run successfully if I use /wait.  If I remove /wait, then I get bizarre errors from the program about not being able to start successfully.

What else might there be that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the program while it runs, you can also use the `/MIN` param, to have it start minimized.

Comment: I think /min will only minimize the program I'm running.  I'm attempting to hide the batch file generated CMD window that is created through the course of launching the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    start /b /wait program.exe